Issues with handling browser back events in Next.js 13
I am currently developing a website using Next.js version 13, and I am having trouble handling the refresh and back events. The code was working fine until recently, but suddenly it stopped working. Here is the code I have now,
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter, usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

const useCustomBack = (route: string) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = '';
    };

    const handlePopState = (event: PopStateEvent) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      router.replace(pathname);
      router.push(route); // I want the page to be redirected to 'route' instead of going back.
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
    };
  }, [router, pathname]);
};

export default useCustomBack;

the issue seems to be that the popstate event handler is not being called when I click the back button in the browser.
please help..........

Next.js’s App Router has removed support for listening to router events like popstate, making it impossible to handle browser back events either natively via nextjs or manually through DOM events. This is a mess.
